# All our garden plants appear to be dying

Tags: trees, diagnosis, shrubs

I have a red Acer tree about two to three feet tall, two Hydrangeas and a Buddleia all of which appear to be dying, leaves shrivelling up.  We have just returned from a week away and are horrified to see what has happened. It looks like Ash dieback but I realise it can't be that.  One Hydrangea is in a large pot, and everything else is planted in the garden.

Any suggestions on how we can solve this?

Comment: Can you post photographs of the plants in question? Where do you live and what was the weather like while you were away? Are the plants new or established? Did you have anyone caring for the plants?

Comment: Need more info along the lines requested by previous comment...